# windows 7 ultimate to work with lexmark X1180 all in one printer

Tags: windows-7, installation, lexmark-printer, all-in-one

I am having problems connecting my Lexmark X1180 all in one printer to my laptop which is HP, Windows 7 Ultimate. I have lost the disk and looking to download online and can not find a matching software to download the driver.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows 64-bit](http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=content&id=DR10850&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&segment=SUPPORT&productCode=LEXMARK_X1180&locale=EN&userlocale=EN_US&searchid=1330298968732) and [Windows 32-bit](http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=content&id=DR8881&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&segment=SUPPORT&productCode=LEXMARK_X1180&locale=EN&userlocale=EN_US&searchid=1330298968732) drivers for the [Lexmark X1180 AIO](http://support.lexmark.com/index?locale=en&startover=y&userlocale=EN_US&question=x1180&productCode=LEXMARK_X1180&page=answers&detectedProductFacet=CMS-CATEGORY_REF.LEXMARK.PRODUCTS.ALLINONE.LEXMARK_X1180&searchid=1330298967629#2)